# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException in WAS 8.5.5.2

Tags: java, web-services, websphere-8

I am getting the below error while deploying my application in WAS 8.5.5.2. Any inputs from experts would really appreciated?

My application doesnt have any physical WSDL files to add. Where can i set the username and password to resolve this issue.

```
 javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error: The javax.xml.ws.security.auth.username property was set, but no value was specified.
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:118)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.setupProperties(AxisInvocationController.java:507)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.initOperationClient(AxisInvocationController.java:407)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:103)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:419)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.getAnnotations(Unknown Source)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.myapp.servlet.ViewerGetAnnot.getAnnotations(ViewerGetAnnot.java:263)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.myapp.servlet.ViewerGetAnnot.doGet(ViewerGetAnnot.java:122)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 [11/25/15 2:19:41:643 PST] 0000008e SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
```

Comment: How did you set username property for your client in the application? You need to check this and set the username value at the same location.

Comment: HI, I am not setting username anywhere. Is there any configuration file (xml or props file) related to this setting? I will there whether anything setting there...